# ModuleNotFound error for import pandas in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I get a moduleNotFoundError when importing pandas in my Jupyter Notebook.
There is not error when I do the same on the Terminal. The default python on my machine is python 3.8

[This is the code that i am running on Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJykT.png)

Why Jupyter is unable to find the pandas installed on my machine?

Comment: `jupyter` does not necesseraliy run your default `python`, maybe you installed `jupyter` with `python2.7` or another version. Try running `import sys; print(sys.version)` in your `jupyter-session` to make sure they are the same.

Comment: The version printed is the same as default

Comment: Then also make sure that `pandas` is installed on your default `python`. If you are using `pip`  then `python -m pip freeze` will list all installed packages, and `python -m pip install pandas` will install it. If  you have `python2.7` on your computer, `pip` may refer to `python2.7 -m pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed caused by different versions of python. Jupyter is not executing the default version installed on my system.
To fetch the right version we need to use `print(sys.executable)`.

Thus, the following code worked for me,

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas
```